# Concatenate multiple rows of integers that are stored in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen plenty of explanations on how to concatenate rows, but the error I keep getting is

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

I've never attempted anything like this before. Each QID is unique, and paired with an AppID. Each AppID can have more than one QID. I don't want to display the AppID, only a concatenated list of QID's for each block of AppID's.

```
    SELECT QID = STUFF((
             SELECT ',' + QID
                FROM Table1
                FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

I expect it to return each value of the row, separated by commas, but instead, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Based on the error `QID` is an int, so you need to cast/convert it to a string before adding the comma to it.

Comment: Curious why you didn't use the `string_agg` function for this

Answer (score 4):

I think you're very close. The error you're recieving is because your `QID` column is not `VARCHAR` and you're trying to stuff it with a character (Try: `CAST(QID AS VARCHAR)`. Also, your full query should have a `WHERE` inside your `STUFF` query and also grouping the table by the `AppID` column. Try this query:

```
SELECT AppID, STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(QID AS VARCHAR) FROM Table1 t1 
                     WHERE t1.AppID = t2.AppID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS QID
FROM Table1 t2
GROUP BY t2.AppID
```

Sample Results:

```
INPUT
-----------------
AppID     QID
 A          1
 A          2
 A          3
 A          4
 B          5
 B          6
 B          7
 C          8
 C          9
 C         10
 C         11

OUTPUT
-----------------
AppID     QID
 A         1,2,3,4
 B         5,6,7
 C         8,9,10,11
```